# Vuex modules state is not updating on hot reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I have setup hot reloading and dynamic loading of my vuex modules.

*store.js file* - hot update section

```
if (module.hot) {
  // accept actions and mutations as hot modulesLoader
  module.hot.accept([
    './store/modules/index.js',
    './store/helpers/global-actions',
    './store/helpers/global-mutations',
    ...modulePaths,
    // './store/helpers/global-actions',
  ], () => {
    let newModules = require('./store/modules').modules
    store.hotUpdate({
      actions: require('./store/helpers/global-actions'),
      mutations: require('./store/helpers/global-mutations'),
      modules: newModules,
    })
  })
}
```

*modules/index.js file*

```
const requireModule = require.context('.', true, /index.js$/)
const modules = {}
const modulePaths = []

requireModule.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  if (fileName === './index.js') {
    modulePaths.push(fileName.replace('./', './store/modules/'))
    return
  } else {
    let moduleName = fileName.match(/(?<=\/)\w*(?=\/)/g)[0]
    modulePaths.push(fileName.replace('./', './store/modules/'))
    modules[moduleName] =
      {
        namespaced: false,
        ...requireModule(fileName),
      }
  }
})

export {modulePaths, modules}
```

Basically what this code does is loading folders with index.js file as modules (where module name is foldername) dynamically.

If I update module actions or getters or mutations everything works as expected I do get new actions added to store as well as mutations, when either of modules is updated.

The only thing I can't get to work is to get modules state changed on update. So if I change modules state it does not get reflected. Is it a normal behaviour? Or am I doing something wrong?